# Documentation on not calling viewDidLoad directly?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

The `[UIViewController viewDidLoad]` method is called by the system after loading the associated view (*obviously?*). A common belief -- which I share -- is that `viewDidLoad` should not be called directly †. However, I can't find this guidance in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621495-viewdidload#discussion), nor anything else from Apple. Does it exist?

For comparison, the `loadView` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) says

> You should never call this method directly.

---

† Excepting `[super viewDidLoad]` in an overridden method.

Comment: I think it's just understood that various "lifecycle" methods called by the framework should never be called directly. This includes all of the `view[Did|Will][A|Disa]appear` methods, etc. They are called to let you know something specific has happened. Any such method in any class should never be called explicitly by your own code.

Comment: Obviously I agree, but I would also expect this important detail to be explicitly spelled out by Apple _somewhere_.

Comment: I would suggest that that they might feel compelled to explicitly warn you to not call `loadView` yourself because unlike the `did`/`will` methods, you cannot reasonably infer this from the method name, alone. With the various `did`/`will` methods, the intent is clear, but it's not inherently obvious in method names like `loadView` (nor in `draw(_:)`, which shares a similar warning). The `loadView` just doesn't follow standard naming conventions for callback methods, so the documentation tries to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: Small addendum to the footnote, the documentation of [UIViewController viewDidLoad] does not say that [super viewDidLoad] needs to be called when you override it. Curiously enough, the template that Xcode provides still does it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not mentioned explicitly but if you would call it, you would somehow violate the "contract" of the method specified in its documentation:

> Called after the controller's view is loaded into memory.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any rule that forbids it. I don't mean "there's a rule we all know, it's just not written down." I mean "I don't think there's any rule that forbids it." You are, as best I am aware, free to call `viewDidLoad` whenever appropriate (including its `super`).

That doesn't mean you *should* call it. But then you almost certainly should never call `OSCompareAndSwap` either. In both cases, if you had a good reason and knew what you were doing, it could be appropriate to call. But it's unlikely to come up.

While I can't think of a time I've had to call `viewDidLoad` directly, I have had to manually call `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` to manage view lifecycle in a custom container view controller. There's nothing that forbids calling view lifecycle methods if that's what you mean.

That said, it would be bad practice to call a view lifecycle method if you *didn't* mean "the view has transitioned into this state." And since it's pretty hard to get into a situation where you have loaded the view, but `viewDidLoad` won't be called, it's hard to imagine many cases where it would be useful. And you shouldn't call a method uselessly. So that's the only rule at play here as far as I'm aware.

Comment: :o manually calling `viewWillAppear`.. why in the world did you ever need to do that.. I've written tons of containers and never once did I need to call that.

Comment: I can't remember the full reason. It was around the iOS 4-5 days, and something didn't call the lifecycle methods. I can't remember if it was tab view controllers or if we had built our own version of tab view controllers that needed it. But, agreed, I haven't had to do it in years.